# Can a React portal be used in a Stateless Functional Component (SFC)?

Tags: reactjs

I have used `ReactDOM.createPortal` inside the render method of a stateful component like so:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    ...
    render() {
        return (
            <Wrapper>
                {ReactDOM.createPortal(<FOO />, 'dom-location')}
            </Wrapper>
        )
    }
}
```

... but can it also be used by a stateless (functional) component?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It can be done like this for a fixed component:

```
const MyComponent = () => ReactDOM.createPortal(<FOO/>, 'dom-location')
```

or, to make the function more flexible, by passing a `component` prop:

```
const MyComponent = ({ component }) => ReactDOM.createPortal(component, 'dom-location')
```

Comment: Yes but as @Denys Kotsur told passing element to be created via props as a children will be better approach.

Comment: Extremely useful answer.

Answer (score 53):

Will chime in with an option where you dont want to manually update your index.html and add extra markup, this snippet will dynamically create a div for you, then insert the children.

```js
export const Portal = ({ children, className = 'root-portal', el = 'div' }) => {
  const [container] = React.useState(() => {
    // This will be executed only on the initial render
    // https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state
    return document.createElement(el);
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    container.classList.add(className)
    document.body.appendChild(container)
    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(container)
    }
  }, [])

  return ReactDOM.createPortal(children, container)
}
```

Comment: I don't know how this didn't get more attention. This is a really dynamic well put solution, reusable across a lot of different scenarios!

Comment: I would use `useRef` instead of `useState`, not sure if it makes a performance difference, but I think that way would be better.


I would also include `classNames` and `el` in the array of useEffect so that the DOM updates when the parent causes updates in the Component.

I'm not sure if my suggestions are valid (I'm new to React & TS) so please tell me if they aren't so that I can learn from my mistakes.

Comment: useRef would look like this:

`const container = useRef(document.createElement(el));`

then use `container.current`

Answer (score 7):

> **can it also be used by a stateless (functional) component
>   ?**

yes.

```
const Modal = (props) => {
      const modalRoot = document.getElementById('myEle');

      return ReactDOM.createPortal(props.children, modalRoot,);
    }
```

Inside render :

```
render() {
    const modal = this.state.showModal ? (
      <Modal>
        <Hello/>
        </Modal>
    ) : null;

    return (
      <div>
      <div id="myEle">
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Working [`codesandbox#demo`](https://codepen.io/riyajk/pen/MVmzMb?editors=0011)

Answer (score 7):

TSX version based on @Samuel's answer (React 17, TS 4.1):

```
// portal.tsx
import * as React from 'react'
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

interface IProps {
    className? : string
    el? : string
    children : React.ReactNode
}

/**
 * React portal based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/59154364
 * @param children Child elements
 * @param className CSS classname
 * @param el HTML element to create.  default: div
 */
const Portal : React.FC<IProps> = ( { children, className, el = 'div' } : IProps ) => {
    
    const [container] = React.useState(document.createElement(el))
    
    if ( className )
        container.classList.add(className)

    React.useEffect(() => {
        document.body.appendChild(container)
        return () => {
            document.body.removeChild(container)
        }
    }, [])

    return ReactDOM.createPortal(children, container)
}

export default Portal
```

Answer (score 4):

## IMPORTANT useRef/useState to prevent bugs

It's important that you use useState or useRef to store the element you created via document.createElement because otherwise it gets recreated on every re-render

```
//This div with id of "overlay-portal" needs to be added to your index.html or for next.js _document.tsx
const modalRoot = document.getElementById("overlay-portal")!;


//we use useRef here to only initialize el once and not recreate it on every rerender, which would cause bugs
  const el = useRef(document.createElement("div"));

  useEffect(() => {
    modalRoot.appendChild(el.current);

    return () => {
      modalRoot.removeChild(el.current);
    };
  }, []);

return ReactDOM.createPortal(
      <div
        onClick={onOutSideClick}
        ref={overlayRef}
        className={classes.overlay}
      >
        <div ref={imageRowRef} className={classes.fullScreenImageRow}>
          {renderImages()}
        </div>
        <button onClick={onClose} className={classes.closeButton}>
          <Image width={25} height={25} src="/app/close-white.svg" />
        </button>
      </div>,
    el.current
  );
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, according to [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) the main requirements are:

> The first argument (child) is any renderable React child, such as an element, string, or fragment. The second argument (container) is a DOM element.

In case of stateless component you can pass element via props and render it via portal.

Hope it will helps.

Answer (score 3):

### Portal with SSR (NextJS)

If you are trying to use any of the above with SSR (for example NextJS) you may run into difficulty.

The following should get you what you need. This methods allows for passing in an id/selector to use for the portal which can be helpful in some cases, otherwise it creates a default using **`__ROOT_PORTAL__`**.

If it can't find the selector then it will create and attach a div.

**NOTE**: you could also statically add a div and specify a known id in  `pages/_document.tsx` (or .jsx) if again using NextJS. Pass in that id and it will attempt to find and use it.

```
import { PropsWithChildren, useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom';

export interface IPortal {
  selector?: string;
}

const Portal = (props: PropsWithChildren<IPortal>) => {

  props = {
    selector: '__ROOT_PORTAL__',
    ...props
  };

  const { selector, children } = props;

  const ref = useRef<Element>()
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);

  const selectorPrefixed = '#' + selector.replace(/^#/, '');

  useEffect(() => {

    ref.current = document.querySelector(selectorPrefixed);

    if (!ref.current) {
      const div = document.createElement('div');
      div.setAttribute('id', selector);
      document.body.appendChild(div);
      ref.current = div;
    }

    setMounted(true);

  }, [selector]);

  return mounted ? createPortal(children, ref.current) : null;

};

export default Portal;
```

### Usage

The below is a quickie example of using the portal. It does NOT take into account position etc. Just something simple to show you usage. Sky is limit from there :)

```
import React, { useState, CSSProperties } from 'react';
import Portal from './path/to/portal'; // Path to above

const modalStyle: CSSProperties = {
  padding: '3rem',
  backgroundColor: '#eee',
  margin: '0 auto',
  width: 400
};

const Home = () => {

  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <p>Hello World <a href="#" onClick={() => setVisible(true)}>Show Modal</a></p>
      <Portal>
        {visible ? <div style={modalStyle}>Hello Modal! <a href="#" onClick={() => setVisible(false)}>Close</a></div> : null}
      </Portal>
    </>
  );

};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const X = ({ children }) =>  ReactDOM.createPortal(children, 'dom-location')
```

Comment: A one-liner code snippet does not provide a full answer. Elaboration is more than welcome on any given answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing my solution:

```
// PortalWrapperModal.js

import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import $ from 'jquery';

const PortalWrapperModal = ({
  children,
  onHide,
  backdrop = 'static',
  focus = true,
  keyboard = false,
}) => {
const portalRef = useRef(null);

const handleClose = (e) => {
    if (e) e.preventDefault();
    if (portalRef.current) $(portalRef.current).modal('hide');
  };

useEffect(() => {
    if (portalRef.current) {
      $(portalRef.current).modal({ backdrop, focus, keyboard });
      $(portalRef.current).modal('show');
      $(portalRef.current).on('hidden.bs.modal', onHide);
    }
  }, [onHide, backdrop, focus, keyboard]);

return ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <>{children(portalRef, handleClose)}</>,
    document.getElementById('modal-root')
  );
};

export { PortalWrapperModal };
```